# Question on what to feed into the loss function

Tags: pytorch

```
def fit(num_epochs, model, loss_fn, opt, train_dl):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for xb,yb in train_dl:
            pred = model(xb)
            loss = loss_fn(pred, yb)
```

`train_dl` is just a dataset split up by DataLoader into suitable batches. `Model()` is the activation function.  Anyways, why is the loss calculated using yb instead of xb? This is a tutorial code for calculating loss, and I was thinking that the code should be looking something like this instead.

```
def fit(num_epochs, model, loss_fn, opt, train_dl):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for xb in train_dl:
            pred = model(xb)
            loss = loss_fn(pred, xb)
```

The tutorial is from this website. https://jovian.ai/aakashns/02-linear-regression

Comment: Loss function calculates the difference between prediction and model's output. So you need to fed it with `true label` and `prediction` , then it calculates the error.

Comment: `Model()` is not activation function. First snippet is correct.

Comment: Your question isn’t about programming so much as it’s about statistics and machine learning theory. It’s better suited for our sister site [stats.SE].